# What's the benefit of wrapping an insert into a transacation in Postgres or other relational database servers?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, insert

I'm trying to increase the `insert into` number per second on Postgres. Now I can insert into around 200-300 rows into a table per second.

I found the ORM I'm using on node.js, TypeORM. Default to wrap every `insert` with transaction as its comments on source code

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/repository/SaveOptions.ts#L18-L22

```js
 /**
     * By default transactions are enabled and all queries in persistence operation are wrapped into the transaction.
     * You can disable this behaviour by setting { transaction: false } in the persistence options.
     */
    transaction?: boolean;
```

if i set it to `false` without transaction which increased around `100` per second. I know transaction can make multiple sql commands to have atom ability, if one of the command failed, postgres will recover it. But why Typeorm default to wrap `.save` api to enable transaction? since one single `.save` only send a `insert into` once without other SQL statement.

What's the benefit of wrapping an `insert into` in a transaction in Postgres or other RDBMS?

Comment: It depends only on the application logic, not related to the RDBMS itself. Hint: instead of the bunch of inserts use single insert with multiple rows or [`copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command (if your framework allows it)

Comment: yeah. `COPY` should help but it needs a file as input source i will skip this option for now. My goal is to increate it to around 1000 `INSERT` per second. i think 200-300 `INSERT` per second shouldn't be the limit of Postgres. I'm looking for what caused this speed now ( might be Typeorm in Node.js ). do u know what's the benefit of wrapping each `INSERT` to a transaction?

Comment: after digging more i assume the transaction added by Typeorm is not useful when wrapping on single `INSERT` but the api `.save` is more than single `INSERT` sometimes. it also handles saving to relations. The case i'm handling is not relation related. i'll change to `INSERT` only without transaction by `Entity.save({ transaction: false })`. refers to : https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0aa79173e667e193cee653492176a43eb06abcd5/src/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.ts#L104-L106

Comment: end up i changed to `insert into multiple rows`. now it can insert 8000 rows / second. but i have to add a queue for this purpose. test script without queue:https://github.com/JaosnHsieh/node-postgres-insert-speed-test/tree/master/typeorm-queryWithInsert

Comment: My congrats! You have exceeded your goal 8 times :) PS: The benefits of wrapping each `insert` into a transaction is that when something goes wrong each completed `insert` will be stored in the DB. In case of single transaction all changes will be canceled.

Comment: @Abelisto, it's not wrapping multiple insert into a transaction. it's wrapping 1 single insert into a transaction. if 1 single insert failed, it won't change any data. so there is no benefit to wrap single insert to a transaction. right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand most of what you wrote, since I don't know typeorm. But I can answer the question what the benefit of wrapping `INSERT` statements into a transaction is.

All relational database that provide ACID guarantees will write a transaction log that is used to replay the transaction in the case of a crash or to recover from a backup. This transaction log has to be persisted to disk at the end of every transaction.

Now if you run 1000 `INSERT` statements in a single transaction, the transaction log has to be persisted only once. But if each `INSERT` runs in its own transaction (the default in PostgreSQL), you'll end up with 1000 I/O requests to persist the transaction log. That will clearly affect performance.

Comment: Why each `INSERT` runs in its own transaction is the default in postgres? afaik, when we wanna start a transaction, we put SQL statements between `BEGIN;`  ..... `COMMIT;`.  We can put `INSERT` without it, isn't it?

Comment: do u know what's the benefit of wrapping each `INSERT` to a transaction?

Comment: You don't have to wrap each `INSERT` in a transaction, that happens by default if you don't start an explicit transaction. You cannot run a statement without having a transaction in PostgreSQL. All you can do is specify that several statements run in the same transaction (by starting the transaction explicitly).